# Python remove newlines from a column in csv file

Tags: python

I tried lot of suggestions but I am unable to remove carriage returns. I am new python and trying it with csv file cleaning.

```
import csv
filepath_i = 'C:\Source Files\Data Source\Flat File Source\PatientRecords.csv'
filepath_o = 'C:\Source Files\Data Source\Flat File Source\PatientRecords2.csv'
rows = []
with open(filepath_i, 'rU', newline='') as csv_file:
     #filtered = (line.replace('\r\n', '') for line in csv_file)
    filtered = (line.replace('\r', '') for line in csv_file)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    i = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
        i = i + 1
        if(i == 10):
            break
    #with open(filepath_o, 'w',newline='' ) as writeFile:
    #    writer = csv.writer(writeFile,lineterminator='\r')
    #    for row in csv_reader:
    #        #rows.append(row.strip()) 
    #        rows.append(row.strip()) 
    #    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Input

```
DRG Definition,Provider Id,Provider Name,Provider Street Address,Provider City,Provider State,Provider Zip Code,Hospital Referral Region Description,Hospital Category,Hospital Type, Total Discharges ,Covered Charges , Total Payments ,Medicare Payments
039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC,10001,SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER,1108 ROSS CLARK CIRCLE,DOTHAN,AL,36301,AL - Dothan,Specialty Centers,Government Funded,91,"$32,963.07 ","$5,777.24 ","$4,763.73 "
039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC,10005,MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH,"2505 U S HIGHWAY 
431 NORTH",BOAZ,AL,35957,AL - Birmingham,Specialty Centers,Private Institution,14,"$15,131.85 ","$5,787.57 ","$4,976.71 "
039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC,10006,ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL,205 MARENGO STREET,FLORENCE,AL,35631,AL - Birmingham,Rehabilitation Centers,Private Institution,24,"$37,560.37 ","$5,434.95 ","$4,453.79 "
```

Output (4th column 'Provider Street Address')

```
['DRG Definition', 'Provider Id', 'Provider Name', 'Provider Street Address', 'Provider City', 'Provider State', 'Provider Zip Code', 'Hospital Referral Region Description', 'Hospital Category', 'Hospital Type', ' Total Discharges ', 'Covered Charges ', ' Total Payments ', 'Medicare Payments']
['039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC', '10001', 'SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER', '1108 ROSS CLARK CIRCLE', 'DOTHAN', 'AL', '36301', 'AL - Dothan', 'Specialty Centers', 'Government Funded', '91', '$32,963.07 ', '$5,777.24 ', '$4,763.73 ']
['039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC', '10005', 'MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH', '2505 U S HIGHWAY \n431 NORTH', 'BOAZ', 'AL', '35957', 'AL - Birmingham', 'Specialty Centers', 'Private Institution', '14', '$15,131.85 ', '$5,787.57 ', '$4,976.71 ']
```

Comment: did you try strip() ?

Comment: ya I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: can u try with pandas and read_csv function in pandas ?

Comment: It worked with pandas, but my target application is not supporting external package. so I am trying with base methods.

Comment: csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"') <- this would read csv properly, and then you can handle the linebreaks as usual

Comment: if I copy-past your input data to a text file, I can already see that `.split(',')` will give me `list`s of different length (14, 17, 4, 14, 17, to be exact) - how is that supposed to go into a regular n by m table? Furthermore, if you read the file and remove all `newline` bytes (or cr lf, whatever), how should your program know where a row starts/ends?

Comment: @MrFuppes we are not supposed to split by ',' . This csv file has quotes for special columns containing linebreaks or ',' itself as values in them. we have to read it differently.

Comment: @Gokul so what's the purpose of using a csv then? The idea of that is to separate by comma as the name says... I'd suggest you make that clear in the question, e.g. if this is about 'cleaning' a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran this on my side and it works:

```
with open(filepath_i, 'rU', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        row[3] = row[3].replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
['DRG Definition', 'Provider Id', 'Provider Name', 'Provider Street Address', 'Provider City', 'Provider State', 'Provider Zip Code', 'Hospital Referral Region Description', 'Hospital Category', 'Hospital Type', ' Total Discharges ', 'Covered Charges ', ' Total Payments ', 'Medicare Payments']
['039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC', '10001', 'SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER', '1108 ROSS CLARK CIRCLE', 'DOTHAN', 'AL', '36301', 'AL - Dothan', 'Specialty Centers', 'Government Funded', '91', '$32,963.07 ', '$5,777.24 ', '$4,763.73 ']
['039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC', '10005', 'MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH', '2505 U S HIGHWAY 431 NORTH', 'BOAZ', 'AL', '35957', 'AL - Birmingham', 'Specialty Centers', 'Private Institution', '14', '$15,131.85 ', '$5,787.57 ', '$4,976.71 ']
['039 - EXTRACRANIAL PROCEDURES W/O CC/MCC', '10006', 'ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL', '205 MARENGO STREET', 'FLORENCE', 'AL', '35631', 'AL - Birmingham', 'Rehabilitation Centers', 'Private Institution', '24', '$37,560.37 ', '$5,434.95 ', '$4,453.79 ']
```